# Using a variable in LIKE '%' + @variable brings back wrong results

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have the following query (simplified) in MS SQL:

```
DECLARE @Search nvarchar(4) = '883C'
SELECT DISTINCT
COUNT(DISTINCT [t].[column1])
FROM [dbo].[Table] [t]
WHERE
([t].[column1] LIKE '%' + @Search
 OR [t].[column2] LIKE '%' + @Search
 OR [t.].[column3] LIKE '%' + @Search
 )
```

If I run this query, I get a count of 1, which is incorrect.

If I change the query to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
COUNT(DISTINCT [t].[column1])
FROM [dbo].[Table] [t]
WHERE
([t].[column1] LIKE '%' + '883C'
 OR [t].[column2] LIKE '%' + '883C'
 OR [t.].[column3] LIKE '%' + '883C'
 )
```

I get a count of 3, which is correct.

Does anyone know why there would be a difference?
I can provide some sample data if required.

Comment: What happens if you make all of the string literals in example 2 be `nvarchar` literals (e.g. `N'%' + N'883C'`)?

Comment: *I can provide some sample data if required.*  -- Please do

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that column1 was nvarchar, column2 was varchar, and column3 was char.

I think Damien was on the right track.